# How to use Firestore ID correctly when selecting a position to update

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on getting an update to work using Firebase Firestore. I currently can click a position in my RecyclerView and get the relative information from there into my edit text boxes. However, my current problem is that I am struggling to select the correct ID to update. I am trying to figure out how I can use my code for the original select position when it comes to updating.

Currently when I click the position I have a toast display showing the correct ID and position, it then takes you to my update activity where when I click save it displays an incorrect ID. I am trying to get this ID to match so I can then get my update to work correctly.

I have currently played around to get the code to work correctly but had no luck. One thing I have done is change my code so that when I click update it tells me which ID it is selecting. When doing this it has led to it selecting the wrong id/random id. This has led me to think my issue lies with selecting the ID.

ReadActivity

Here is my code for the when you select the position in the RecyclerView. This currently works correctly and selects the correct ID.

```
             public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                Book book = documentSnapshot.toObject(Book.class);
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
                Toast.makeText(AdminReadActivity.this,
                        "Position: " + position + " ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String chapterName = adapter.getItem(position).getChapterName();
                String chapterInfo = adapter.getItem(position).getChapterInfo();
                Integer chapterNumber = adapter.getItem(position).getChapterNumber();



                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminReadActivity.this, AdminUpdateActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("mChapterName", chapterName);
                intent.putExtra("mChapterInfo", chapterInfo);
                intent.putExtra("mChapterNumber", chapterNumber);
                intent.putExtra("mMyId", id);

                startActivity(intent);
```

EDITED: UpdateActivity

Here is my updateBook method. So far this just display the incorrect ID.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.save_icon:
                updateBook();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminUpdateActivity.this, AdminReadActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


private void updateBook() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");

        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference bookRef = db.collection("Book").document(id);
        bookRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                DocumentReference bookRef = db.collection("Book").document(id);
                Toast.makeText(AdminUpdateActivity.this, " ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }
```

BookAdapter

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null)//ensure the user does not click deleted items
                    {
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });

 public interface OnItemClickListener    {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest how I can get the ID when I click save in the UpdateActivity to display the correct and same ID that it does when I first select it from the RecyclerView.

Upon changing I now get this error from within the OnOptionSelected and the UpdateBook() class.

EDIT: Added error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:906)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:110)
        at com.example.home.optometryapplication.AdminUpdateActivity.updateBook(AdminUpdateActivity.java:155)
        at com.example.home.optometryapplication.AdminUpdateActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(AdminUpdateActivity.java:101)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3204)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:407)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:108)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:674)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:171)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:973)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:963)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:624)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:150)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the ID to the UpdateActivity through the OnItemClick Method

```
public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
            Book book = documentSnapshot.toObject(Book.class);
            String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
            String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
            Toast.makeText(AdminReadActivity.this,
                    "Position: " + position + " ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String chapterName = adapter.getItem(position).getChapterName();
            String chapterInfo = adapter.getItem(position).getChapterInfo();
            Integer chapterNumber = adapter.getItem(position).getChapterNumber();

            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminReadActivity.this, AdminUpdateActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("mChapterName", chapterName);
            intent.putExtra("mChapterInfo", chapterInfo);
            intent.putExtra("mChapterNumber", chapterNumber);
            intent.putExtra("mId", id); // Add this line

            startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your UpdateActivity get the ID (the same way you got the mChapterName, mChapterInfo...) and use this ID in your UpdateBook1() method

```
private void updateBook1() {

    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference bookRef = db.collection("Book").document(id); // ID got from the Intent Extras

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have updated it as you have mentioned. I am unsure if I have added the Intent extras correctly. I now get a NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null. i have updated my code, is this what you have meant in regard to Intent Extras?

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerExecption? Can you show me the Error log

Comment: Sorry for taking your time. You are using a wrong reference to get the ID. Change `String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");` to `String id = intent.getStringExtra("mMyId");`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. This seems to have worked now:)